# Angularjs ng-animate fadein but it disappears?

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

HTML:

```
.popup
  .notification(ng-show="showNow", ng-animate="{show: 'animate-enter'}")
     | Notification text
```

CSS:

```
.popup
  .notification
    transition-duration 3s
    transition-timing-function ease
    transition-property all
    opacity 0
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    left: 200px;
    top: 110px;
    z-index: 9;
    background: darkorange;
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
    color #FFF
    line-height 1.5
    transform translateY(0px)

.popup
  .notification.animate-enter-start
    opacity 1
    transform translateY(-10px)
```

I'm trying to animate a popup getting it to fadein. The fade in works, but then right after the fadein animation plays it fades back out again. How do I get it to stay faded-in?

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Xyys/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSS is the problem.

You need to set the final properties to the permanent class `.popup .notification`.
Then, you need to set the initial parameters at the active class, and then the final parameters at the start class again.

You need to do this, because the classes `animate-enter` and `animate-enter-start` will be removed after the animation, so the final properties needs to be at the `.popup .notification` class. So, you need to set the opacity to 1 at this class.

Give us a fiddle than we can help you better.

Permanent Class:

```
.popup
  .notification
    opacity 1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    left: 200px;
    top: 110px;
    z-index: 9;
    background: darkorange;
    padding: 1rem 1rem;
    color #FFF
    line-height 1.5
    transform translateY(-10px)
```

Setup Class:

```
.popup
  .notification.animate-enter-setup
    transition-duration 3s
    transition-timing-function ease
    transition-property all
    opacity 0
    transform translateY(0px)
```

Start Animation Class:

```
.popup
  .notification.animate-enter-start
    opacity 1
    transform translateY(-10px)
```

Look some samples at this site:
[ng-animate move sample](http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-repeat/move)

Comment: Is there documentation on what exactly ng-animate does in the background?

Comment: I'm trying it as you demonstrated but this causes the element to always be shown instead of fading in.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6Xyys/ I'm actually not sure if I'm setting up the  fiddle correctly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: First, update your angular version to 1.1.5, it has some important diferences... Second, because of this update, you will need to change the class `animate-enter-setup` to `animate-enter-active`. Third, set the translation to your permanent class. The new fiddle working: http://jsfiddle.net/6Xyys/1/

Comment: Do you think you can use 1.1.4 for this question? There's some bugs in 1.1.5 in regards to routing that forcing me to stay on 1.1.4 for now.

Comment: The beginning of this answer still applies to Angular 8+; Make sure your CSS has the final properties, i.e. no `display: none;` in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

All the above fiddle will not work with latest angular. Updated them for Angular 1.4. http://jsfiddle.net/rsarosh/npzLLwL1/3/

HTML

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script>
  angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);

</script>
<div ng-app="app" class="popup">
  <button ng-click="showNow = true">activate</button>
  <div ng-if="showNow" class="notification">
    <div>Some sample text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.popup .notification {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  left: 200px;
  top: 110px;
  z-index: 99;
  background: #ff8c00;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.5;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
  transform: translateY(-30px);
}

.notification.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px);
  transition-duration: 10s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-property: all;
}

.notification.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
  transform: translateY(-30px);
}
```

Read more http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html